# VideoView overlapping the navigation layout

Tags: android, xml, android-videoview

I'm trying to play video in videoview from mobile memory, i'm using Navigation view and fragments,when single view in xml then no overlapping but when i make another view and after playing video the videoview comes infront of navigation layout, attached screenshot,  i already used `NavigationView.bringToFront();` 
**the boelow answers didn't solve my problem** but somehow i managed to solve it doing a little confusing things,
below code is my previous code, now i changed it into
->Parent ScrollView inner LinearLayout, then ImageView, RelativeLayout with bottom gravity and then my VideoView which is above of last TextView and textview which is parentbottom

Here is my xml file **OLD**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/id_IntroimageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

  <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/introVideoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
    />
```

Please check screenshot for better understand.

**UPDATE its occurred when first fragment replacing second time it works fine**

[Embedded screenshot of overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BOuZ.jpg)

My content layout code

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is sequence of my main_activity layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


<include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<LinerLayout.......
/>


   </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In app_bar_main layout here what i'm doing

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
 <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Code is attached for better understanding of problem(requested)

Comment: check "navigation view's" and "videos view's" parent activity is same

Comment: @RohanPawar can you please check the attached main_layout xml code?

Answer (score 1):

try this but change the frame  layout textview conent

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <!--<include
        layout="@layout/new_app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Connect To Internet\n and Try Again "
                android:textColor="@color/google_red"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />



        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/custom_navigation_drawer_tab_menu" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```